# Write allocated memory to disk

Tags: c++

I have an allocated memory and I want to write it to a file. How can I do that in C++ 20?

I know I could do the following sequence, just like in C. However, in C++ there is the `std::filesystem`, can't I do that with it?

- CreateFile
- VirtualAlloc
- memcpy
- WriteFile
- VirtualFree
- CloseHandle

```cpp
auto* const data = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, 0x1000, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

if (!data)
    return 0;
    
memcpy(...);

if (data)
    VirtualFree(data, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
```

Comment: [`std::ofstream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, is there a newer way with std::filesystem?

Comment: I don't think std::filesystem has anything to do with writing  data to files. There is a full reference here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Comment: I will then stick to ofstream::write, thank you! You could write it as an answer in that case.

Comment: What's wrong with the "old" way? You can pass a `std::filesystem::path` when [opening](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) a `std::ofstream`

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I will do that

Comment: Q: What is a legacy system? A: The one we're still using because it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the tried and true method for writing memory to a file:

```
// Open your output_file as binary
static const size_t DATA_CAPACITY = 0x1000;
output_file.write(data, DATA_CAPACITY);
```

This is known as block writing to a binary file (or a file in binary mode).

Comment: `std::ofstream dump_file(dump_path, std::ios::binary);  dump_file.write(static_cast<const char*>(section_data), section_size); dump_file.close();`, just like that?

Comment: You only need the cast if the data is not `char *`.  There are multiple overloads for the `std::ostream::write()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)